# Finding the minimum length of an addition chain

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, graph-theory

It is known that for every positive integer $n$ there exists one or more *optimal* addition chains of minimum length. [It is rumored](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109904/is-finding-the-length-of-the-shortest-addition-chain-for-a-number-n-really-np) that finding the length of the optimal chain is NP-hard, and the [related Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition_chain#Methods_for_computing_addition_chains) only provides methods to calculate relatively short chains but not the optimal chain.

1- What methods exist that can find the optimal addition chain for a given $n$?

2- How fast are these methods and how well do they scale with $n$?

3- Do methods exist that will only calculate the length of the optimal chain and could they be faster than ordinary methods?

4- Could a function that relates to addition chains be *recursive*?

Comment: I seem to remember that there is discussion of this topic in Volume 2 of Knuth *The Art of Computer Programming*, in connection with finding the optimal sequence of multiplications for calculating $x^n$ for given integer $n$.

Comment: The wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation#cite_note-0) provides a reference where NP-completeness is claimed proven.